# How to check which threads are being created/deleted during program execution?

Tags: multithreading, frame-rate

I apologize for my ignorance but I've basic to none knowledge of how thread works. I'm programming a guitar hero like and I realized the very first music I load I get a HUGE performance drop. If I restart the same music or load another one it is ok.

So I thought it should be something related to asset creation, something I forgot to pre-load. I runned gDEbugger and it turned out it prints an absurd amount of "Thread Created/Thread Terminated" right when the fps starts to drop. When these messages stop the game fps rises again. The problem is: if my game is creating these threads I have no idea why, I only create one thread for loading assets, which I start for loading assets and stop when it's done. Maybe I'm messing something up with this thread. The gDebugger has fields that hold info about the thread like which dll created it but all field are filled with "N/A".

One possibility that came to my mind is that GLee (which I'm using for opengl extensions) is creating them . But I've no idea how to look that up. I'm hoping someone knows a tool to debug these threads.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using .NET? Just do a quick search within your project files and look for the word "thread" (case insensitive). There can't be that many places where threads are created, so just take note and debug around those areas. If you're not creating the threads, then some of the code you're using might be creating them, so are you using a 3rd party library or some pre-existing code?

Answer (score 0):

If you think it could be GLee, and if GLee is unrelated to the music assets that you're loading, try stubbing out that code and check to see if the thread creation messages go away.

In fact, you can use this method for other libraries to narrow it down, brute-force style, either by implementing the interface with stubs, or commenting out portions of your code.